# How can I avoid self join in BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, analytic-functions

I have the following table and from there I want to add another column with the previous value:

| id | Previous id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 20 | 8000 |
| 20 | 10 | 5000 |

The output would be as follows:

| id | Previous_id | Value | Previous_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 20 | 8000 | 5000 |
| 20 | 10 | 5000 | - |

I know I could run the self join you can see below, but I want to know if there's a better practice to do so, as this is an operation I will have to run periodically in other similar use cases. I've tried analytic functions but I can't find the solution with them...

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Value as Previous_Value
FROM `Table` t1
LEFT JOIN `Table`t2
ON t1.Previous_id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 4):

The self-join is the right approach because your data is "linked".

If the previous id were strictly the id that comes numerically just before the given id, you could use `LAG()`:

```
SELECT t.*, LAG(t.Value) OVER (ORDER BY t.id) as Previous_Value
FROM `Table` t;
```

However, this is probably not the case in your data (although it is the case in your sample data).

In terms of performance, you don't need to worry too much about the `JOIN`.  It is an equijoin, so BigQuery should know how to run it optimally.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing, but I guess I `LAG`ged too much `:-)`